# Deselect an ID that would otherwise be selected by class

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a page where all inputs are assigned a behavior:
       $("input").blur(function () {

and I need to exclude a checkbox that has a specific id:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="allButMe" onchange="billingSameChanged();" value="true"/>
```

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) like this:

```
$("input:not(#allButMe)").blur(function() { });
```

Comment: @Andrew: Since nobody told whats wrong with my answer, I am asking you, could you please tell me whats wrong with my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) here

```
$("input").not("#allButMe").blur(function() {});
```