# Jquery select all form fields except other fields

Tags: jquery

```
<form id="test">
   <input type="text" name="title" value="I am title">
   <div id="text1">
      <input type="text" name="module-title" value="I am module title">
   </div>
   <div id="test2">
      <input type="text" name="article-title" value="I am article title">
   </div>
</form>
```

How do I select by jquery all the form (i.e. #test) input fields, except all the input fields which are inside "#test2".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710400/deselect-an-id-that-would-otherwise-be-selected-by-class

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WWGFm/

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
$('#test input:text').not('#test2 input:text')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#test :input:not(#test2 :input)')
```

`:input` is a special pseudo-selector which matches all input elements, like `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vudS3/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#test input').not('#test2 *')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WWGFm/).

Note that the `*` in the above code could be replaced by `input` or any other, more-specific, CSS selector.

References:

- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can do this.

```
var formElements = $("#test :input").not('#test2 :input');
```

for more info [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635043/how-to-select-all-form-elements)

Comment: Yes, but he doesn't want to do that because he wants to exclude all the children of the `#test2` element.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick `$('test1').find('input')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the [.not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

in your case:

```
var my form = $('#test').not('#test2');
```

would do the trick.